# What are some intuitions that support calling the Maybe constructor in Haskell "Just"?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, data-types, null

The intuition of an optional type like `Maybe Int` is that either there is **no** Int (thus, there's `Nothing` there) or that there is **some** Int; there is something there.

It makes sense to me that we call the type constructor for the "negative" case `Nothing`, since it means exactly that -- that there's no `Int` there. But why use the word **Just** in the case where the emphasis is on something **actually being there**?

To me, the word "Just" carries the connotation that the thing it's describing is **less** than the alternative; the opposite of something actually being there; for example,

> A: Are you doing anything tonight?
>
> B: No; I'm **just** gonna stay in and watch TV.
>
> A: Did you investigate the creepy ghost sounds around your house?
>
> B: yeah, turns out it was actually **just** an owl.

Clearly I'm lacking whatever intuition this naming choice was based on. What is it? Because to me, the word *Just* means the opposite of how it's used in the `Maybe` type.

Comment: I'm voting to close because I think the answers will be primarily opinion based on speculation.

Comment: @Samuel I tried editing the question to make it less speculation-based, but perhaps now it's not very stackexchange

Comment: I'm not a Haskell history expert, so I can only speculate, but... The Maybe monad either returns `Just` a value, or it returns `Nothing`.  The `Just` keyword substitutes for `return` in most other languages, but since the Maybe monad can return `Nothing`, it is necessary to invoke a different keyword for returning a valid result, and `Just` is suitable because you're returning `Just` the actual value, and not something indicating an error condition.  `Just` is more evocative of an 'either/or' situation than `return` is; you're either returning `Nothing`, or `Just` a value.

Comment: In this case, I think the Scala went with the better name of **Some** as opposed to **None** (not saying it's Scala's invention).

Comment: @AndresF. It goes back at least to ML which Odersky was definitely very familiar with.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If a Haskeller was using `Maybe` as a monad, they would likely use `return` and probably something like `mzero` instead of `Nothing`. When `Just` is used directly, usually `Maybe` isn't being used in monadic style at that point.

Comment: The historical precedent would have been the `Option` type. The designers of Haskell probably felt that `foo x = Just x` "read" better than `foo x = Some x`. Similarly, the definition `data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing` reads pretty well as "`Maybe a` is either `Just a` or it's `Nothing`". `Some` reads reasonably well there, but `None` doesn't for `data Option a = Some a | None`.

Comment: They are still alive. You can email people like Phil Wadler and Simon Peyton Jones and ask them. Or try the Haskell-Cafe mailing list.

Comment: @DerekElkins Right, ML! I forgot about it. And SPJ seems like a genuinely nice guy, he'll likely answer this kind of question :)

Comment: @DerekElkins: I'm not sure a question like this would be all that interesting to those folks.  "You want to know what?  Why I picked 'just'?  Are you serious?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Actually, SPJ *has* explained in pretty much every introductory talk or class I have seen him give that it's called that because it's either "Nothing" or "Just an `a`".

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I don't know much about Wadler, but given that SPJ has a very serious focus on computer science education and evangelism (as well as being a major contributor to Haskell he's also a key player in a major UK charity that campaigns to improve CS education for children) I'd imagine explaining stuff like this is right up his street, so to speak.

Comment: Asking why `Just` was chosen is putting the cart before the horse.  Use the construct long enough, and the meaning of `Just` becomes readily apparent.  One of the differences between adults and children is that adults want to understand something first, before they try it.  Try it first, and then you will understand it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey (I agree with your last comment, btw) I think there's not much SPJ *won't* answer. If you've watched any of his talks, which I highly recommend, you'll see his personality is that of a grown-up kid, tremendously enthusiastic about everything and without an inch of meanness. I don't think he'll dismiss many questions out of hand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm plenty experienced with the idea and usage of the optional type; the name "just" still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @AndresF. I would have gone with simply `Value`.  `Some` makes even less sense to me than `Just`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That'd be confusing, because `Nothing` IS a value (everything has a value in expression-oriented languages). Specifically, it is a value of type `Maybe a`.

Answer (score 1):

This has been explained in the past by Simon Peyton Jones. It implies that either Nothing can be the value or 'just' a single other type value. There is 'just' one other thing that can be returned as a value, or nothing.